# sed replace string except the matched string

Tags: sed

Problem statement:

change every user agent that does not match `A2PC` or `GENCOM` with the user agent `PROHIBITED` and keep `GENCOM` and `A2PC` unchanged

Expression:

```
echo \"GENCOM\" | sed -r -e 's/(^((?!A2PC)(?!GENCOM).)*$)/PROHIBITED/g'
```

error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 41: Invalid preceding regular expression
```

I removed -r then error not thrown but its not working

```
echo \"GENDFGGH\" | sed  -e 's/(^((?!A2PC)(?!GENCOM).)*$)/PROHIBITED/g'
"GENDFGGH"
```

Please help me for this solution

Answer (score 2):

First look for your pattern and then do the sub:

```
# echo \"GENCsOM\" | sed -e '/^"\(GENCOM\|A2PC\)"$/! s/^.*$/PROHIBITED/'
PROHIBITED
# echo \"GENCOM\" | sed -e '/^"\(GENCOM\|A2PC\)"$/! s/^.*$/PROHIBITED/'                                                                        
"GENCOM"
```

Comment: Hi. Its not working fine. nksvm82:/var # echo \"GENCOM\" | sed -e '/^\(GENCOM\|A2PC\)$/! s/^.*$/PROHIBITED/'         answer-->PROHIBITED

Comment: Hi . can you please tell why its not working at my system . also can i use the command in sed -e 's/expression/subsitution/g' format for that what could be the expression so that i can get the solution without changing the code. thanks in advance

Comment: Fails because the quotes , i going to update the post @user3607508

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/A2PC/ !{
   /GENCOM/ ! {
      s/$/PROHIBITED/
      }
   }' YourFile
```

double exclusion than a change, posix compliant